# jQuery script is not working in master page using ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Without using master page it is working perfectly in single page(Default.aspx) in ASP.NET C#. When I am using master page it is not working, still getting why info div is not loading count. Below is the link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js"></script>
```

MasterPage.master code:

```
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js">          </script>



<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

 <div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Default2.aspx code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     var Editor1 = '#Editor1';
     var Editor1CountLimit = 50
     var Editor1InfoArea = '#Info';

     var Editor2 = '#Editor2';
     var Editor1InfoArea1 = '#Info1';

     $(document).ready(function () {
         TrackCharacterCount(Editor1, Editor1CountLimit, Editor1InfoArea);
         TrackCharacterCount(Editor2, Editor1CountLimit, Editor1InfoArea1);
     });

     function TrackCharacterCount(ctl, limit, info) {
         var editor = $(ctl).contents().find('iframe').eq(2);
         $(editor).load(function () {
             var txt = $(this).contents().find('body').text();
             $(info).html(txt.length); //set initial value 
             $(this).contents().keyup(function () {
                 var txt = $(this).contents().find('body').text();

                 if (txt.length > limit)
                     $(info).html(txt.length).css("color", "red");
                 else
                     $(info).html(txt.length).css("color", "");
             });
         });
     }

     function ValidateEditor1Length(source, args) {
         var editor = $(Editor1).contents().find('iframe').eq(2);
         var txt = editor.contents().find('body').text();
         var isValid = txt.length > 0 && txt.length <= Editor1CountLimit;
         args.IsValid = isValid;
     }


     function ValidateEditor1Length1(source, args) {
         var editor = $(Editor2).contents().find('iframe').eq(2);
         var txt = editor.contents().find('body').text();
         var isValid = txt.length > 0 && txt.length <= Editor1CountLimit;
         args.IsValid = isValid;
     }

</script> 


      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>

            <div id="Info">Info</div>

  <%--  <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />--%>
    <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Editor1" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateEditor1Length" ErrorMessage="Exceeded Character Limit"></asp:CustomValidator>


   <div id="Info1">Info</div>
   <%-- <cc1:Editor ID="Editor2" runat="server" />--%>
    <cc1:Editor ID="Editor2" runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Editor2" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateEditor1Length1" ErrorMessage="Exceeded Character Limit"></asp:CustomValidator>

</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, did you omit the </ head> from nasterPage.aspx in your code here on purpose?

Comment: Ya. its under <head></head> block only. Working perfectly in a single page and using master page is not working. @israelaltar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery is not working in Master Page using ASP.NET C# and working fine with without using master page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288723/jquery-is-not-working-in-master-page-using-asp-net-c-sharp-and-working-fine-with)

Comment: you have asked same question 2 times