# Jquery is not working in Master Page using ASP.NET C# and working fine with without using master page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

This code works fine in .aspx page no issues. but if i use master page then nothing works fine here,i tried placing the JQuery script in Master page, even then nothing is working. is there any thing setting need to be done here. Still not getting why info div is not loading count. Below is the link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js"></script>
```

I refer following blog also:

http://mwtech.blogspot.co.il/2009/04/2-ways-to-load-jquery-from-aspnet.html

MasterPage.master code:

```
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js">          </script>



<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

 <div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Default2.aspx code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     var Editor1 = '#Editor1';
     var Editor1CountLimit = 50
     var Editor1InfoArea = '#Info';

     var Editor2 = '#Editor2';
     var Editor1InfoArea1 = '#Info1';

     $(document).ready(function () {
         TrackCharacterCount(Editor1, Editor1CountLimit, Editor1InfoArea);
         TrackCharacterCount(Editor2, Editor1CountLimit, Editor1InfoArea1);
     });

     function TrackCharacterCount(ctl, limit, info) {
         var editor = $(ctl).contents().find('iframe').eq(2);
         $(editor).load(function () {
             var txt = $(this).contents().find('body').text();
             $(info).html(txt.length); //set initial value 
             $(this).contents().keyup(function () {
                 var txt = $(this).contents().find('body').text();

                 if (txt.length > limit)
                     $(info).html(txt.length).css("color", "red");
                 else
                     $(info).html(txt.length).css("color", "");
             });
         });
     }

     function ValidateEditor1Length(source, args) {
         var editor = $(Editor1).contents().find('iframe').eq(2);
         var txt = editor.contents().find('body').text();
         var isValid = txt.length > 0 && txt.length <= Editor1CountLimit;
         args.IsValid = isValid;
     }


     function ValidateEditor1Length1(source, args) {
         var editor = $(Editor2).contents().find('iframe').eq(2);
         var txt = editor.contents().find('body').text();
         var isValid = txt.length > 0 && txt.length <= Editor1CountLimit;
         args.IsValid = isValid;
     }

</script> 


      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>

            <div id="Info">Info</div>

  <%--  <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />--%>
    <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Editor1" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateEditor1Length" ErrorMessage="Exceeded Character Limit"></asp:CustomValidator>


   <div id="Info1">Info</div>
   <%-- <cc1:Editor ID="Editor2" runat="server" />--%>
    <cc1:Editor ID="Editor2" runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Editor2" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateEditor1Length1" ErrorMessage="Exceeded Character Limit"></asp:CustomValidator>

</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the js file being downloaded? Use network under developer tools (F12) too check. Also check in the final page's HTML that the IDs of the controls are really the ones you use in your script.

Comment: Please prefer above link in my question and you will get my answer. @Rui lima

Comment: So is the file being downloaded or not?

Comment: without using master page this code is working perfectly. But when i am working master page with above code jquery is not loading. Please once check above link u will get my problem. @Rui lima

Comment: mate, we don't see the code. The problem is surely related with the way asp.net webforms generates the ID of the control. If you want to fix your problem we will need to make sure two things: 1. make sure the js file is being downloaded and 2. make sure that the IDs are really the correct ones. When using master page sometimes you get IDs as id="ctl00_MainContent_Age" instead of just id="Age". http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs, btw the link you gave is not a very good example.

Comment: Still confused and the above code is available can you find what made the mistake. @Rui Lima

Comment: Still getting confused and can you find above all code is available. @Rui Lima

Comment: I mean the generated HTML code, you know, when you open the page on the browser and then select "View Source". In this "source" you'll need to check that the IDs exist, example "#Editor2" might have a completely different name such as ctl00_MainContent_Editor2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Jquery reference to be like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/scripts/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: ya. Tried this one also but not loading jquery info div and please prefer above link. @Martin

Comment: Have you take a look at Chrome Developer Tools console, is there any Javascript error or missing resources?

Comment: using single page working perfectly and when use master page then giving problem please refer above link.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. When viewing output source code in browser client I noticed that all "ids" were modified with the ContentPlaceHolderID as a prefix before the id itself, so the Id´s jQuery was looking for did not exist anymore.

Solution was to include the parameter ClientIDMode="Static" in the "Content section" of the child page so id objects remain the same on content pages, and jQuery can find it by the original id.

Hope it helps.