# jQuery is not loaded with master page using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

This code works fine in .aspx page no issues. But if I use master page then nothing works fine here. I tried placing the jQuery script in Master page, even then nothing is working. Are there any settings needed to be done here? Still not getting why info div is not loading count. Below is the link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js"></script>
```

I referred following blog also:

http://mwtech.blogspot.co.il/2009/04/2-ways-to-load-jquery-from-aspnet.html

I added below code, script in the master page header also and got from jQuery new version script also.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

MasterPage.master code:

```
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js">          </script>



<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

 <div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Default2.aspx code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     var Editor1 = '#Editor1';
     var Editor1CountLimit = 50
     var Editor1InfoArea = '#Info';

     var Editor2 = '#Editor2';
     var Editor1InfoArea1 = '#Info1';

     $(document).ready(function () {
         TrackCharacterCount(Editor1, Editor1CountLimit, Editor1InfoArea);
         TrackCharacterCount(Editor2, Editor1CountLimit, Editor1InfoArea1);
     });

     function TrackCharacterCount(ctl, limit, info) {
         var editor = $(ctl).contents().find('iframe').eq(2);
         $(editor).load(function () {
             var txt = $(this).contents().find('body').text();
             $(info).html(txt.length); //set initial value 
             $(this).contents().keyup(function () {
                 var txt = $(this).contents().find('body').text();

                 if (txt.length > limit)
                     $(info).html(txt.length).css("color", "red");
                 else
                     $(info).html(txt.length).css("color", "");
             });
         });
     }

     function ValidateEditor1Length(source, args) {
         var editor = $(Editor1).contents().find('iframe').eq(2);
         var txt = editor.contents().find('body').text();
         var isValid = txt.length > 0 && txt.length <= Editor1CountLimit;
         args.IsValid = isValid;
     }


     function ValidateEditor1Length1(source, args) {
         var editor = $(Editor2).contents().find('iframe').eq(2);
         var txt = editor.contents().find('body').text();
         var isValid = txt.length > 0 && txt.length <= Editor1CountLimit;
         args.IsValid = isValid;
     }

</script> 


      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>

            <div id="Info">Info</div>

  <%--  <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />--%>
    <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Editor1" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateEditor1Length" ErrorMessage="Exceeded Character Limit"></asp:CustomValidator>


   <div id="Info1">Info</div>
   <%-- <cc1:Editor ID="Editor2" runat="server" />--%>
    <cc1:Editor ID="Editor2" runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Editor2" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateEditor1Length1" ErrorMessage="Exceeded Character Limit"></asp:CustomValidator>

</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: *it's not working* - the single most unhelpful phrase you can use.  What isn't working? What is it not doing? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing? Are you getting console errors in your browser developer tools? Help us to help you

Comment: Use a single reference of jQuery.

Comment: This is a similar question like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288723/jquery-is-not-working-in-master-page-using-asp-net-c-sharp-and-working-fine-with/30288800#30288800

Comment: But no buddy finding error mistake. @MartinSiagian

Comment: You have two jquery versions(1.3.2 and 1.11.3) added to your code. Use only one.

Comment: I tried that also. @ShaunakD

Comment: Not like that i tried new version also and old version script all are not working.@kurenaiKunai

Comment: is your master page and aspx page at the same level ?

Comment: View source in the browser and see if the link to jQuery.js looks any different here.  Click it to see if it loads the file or returns 404.  (Or use Fiddler to check)

Comment: Ya master page and asp.net is related. @ConnectingKamlesh

Answer (score 0):

looks like jquery is not loaded.

Try to use the online jquery google api or online jquery path as follows

google api path

JQUERY.COM

Comment: //GOOGLE APIs
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//JQUERY.COM
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: I added this also. @Er

Comment: can you please share your code to my email id b.goyal23@gmail.com